# Sorting an array based on a compare model iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, comparator, nssortdescriptor

```
Student *s1 = [Student new];
s1.city = @"Delhi";

Student *s2 = [Student new];
s2.city = @"Mumbai";

NSArray *arrModels = @[s1,s2];
NSArray *arrCompareModel = @[@"Mumbai",@"Delhi"];
```

I need to sort the `arrModels` based `on arrCompareModel`.

All solutions in web are related to ascending. But here I have a custom model.
How do I achieve it?

Comment: Use `sortedArrayUsingComparator:`, you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768463/sort-nsarray-custom-objects-by-another-nsarray-custom-objects/38769228#38769228 with the difference that `indexForItem:inList:` may just be `[arrCompareModel indexOfObject:student1Or2AccordingToTheCase.city];`

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need  to write this for sorting descending

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"city" ascending:false];
NSArray *sortedArray = [arrModels sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
```

Comment: That's not the question. He wants the items ordered based on the order of `arrCompareModel`.

Comment: that is nothing like the OP looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [arrModels sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(Student *obj1, Student *obj2) {
    return [arrCompareModel indexOfObject:obj1.city] < [arrCompareModel indexOfObject:obj2.city];
}];
```